Does Tears of the Kingdom have multiple endings?
Does Tears of the Kingdom have any extra endings you can unlock?
If so, what are they (what does the ending look like), and how do you unlock them? Also, are there any endings that are considered "true?"
Also, once you beat the game and get the golden star next to the save file, can you fulfill requirements for other endings and get those upon recompletion for the game?

To prevent your question from being closed as "needs more focus," I removed the part about Breath of the Wild. It is best practice to focus your question on a single game. Feel free to ask a new question for Breath of the Wild.

No, there is only one ending to TotK
It ends as soon as you defeat Ganondorf, who resides:

 in the depths below hyrule castle

And if you do that, you get the game's ending where:

 Princess Zelda turns back to her hylian form from having been the Light Dragon since the days of King Rauru.

However, if you have:

 Completed all the main quests

There will be some additonal story cutscenes after the intial ending, which some people call the 'True Ending', see here for more details.
The golden star on your save file is just to indicate that you beat the game, which is necessary, as you can't save anymore, once you get close to the final boss. You can then however beat the game as many times as you like, and will get the additional cutscenes, if you fullfill the requirement stated earlier.
Also once you beat the game, there will be a percentage meter at the bottom right of the map, showing you how much of all of the game's content you have completed. Filling this meter to 100% does however not unlook a secret, additional ending.
